# Print view path when rendering page sections

Tags: laravel

I've written this code block into the BladeCompiler class' compile method:

```
if (\Request::exists('debug')) 
{ 
  $contents = '</!--START VIEW '.$this->getPath().'-->'. 
  $contents.'</!--END VIEW '.$this->getPath().'-->'; 
 }
```

The intention is to see what view is in use when using a cascading template setup.

EDIT: to be clear I was aiming to have the view path displayed within the rendered content in this fashion:

```
</!--start view: path to view-->
view
</!--start view: path to view-->
nested view
</!--end view: path to view-->
</!--end view: path to view-->
```

It works but I'm hoping a more experienced laravel dev can suggest a cleaner solution?

Comment: if it's only for dev purposes then you can just use `{{dump($this->getCompiler()->getPath())}}` in view files. Also, which  is better, use [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)

Comment: Fair point Vladyslav but I was intentionally trying to avoid having to add lines of code to every view. I'm also wanting the ability to check the views via a $_GET param even when the Debugbar is disabled i.e. when the site is in production.

Comment: Perhaps aftermiddleware is what you are looking for? [Link with example](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/run-after-middleware-to-manipulate-the-response-content?page=1)

Comment: I could be mistaken but I don't think that middleware would allow me to render the view path at the top of each view within the complete rendered page. Apologies if my description is somewhat unclear...